# Use Google translate library in android app?

Tags: android, translate

I want to make an android translate app can I use this library  "google.api.translate" ?
I read that google translate api has been deprecated

Comment: Google now charges for their API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a web service, not a library. It used to be free, now it's a paid service. Probably, what you have heard is that the free service has been canceled. You may want to consider using Bing Translation API, it's free.